# Pixel value of Sentinel 2A L1C download

Tags: raster, digital-image-processing, sentinel-2, sentinel-snap

As I can read in many posts, it is necessary to convert Sentinel 2 L1C pixel values from Digital Count to TOA reflectance by dividing with the scaling factor.

However when I open my image in SNAP, the values seem to already be in TOA reflectance, or at least between 0-1. I have added my screenshot, showing the histogram and a random pixel value.

Is there an explanation why I see these values, and are they truly in TOA reflectance?

[image]

Comment: The reported value is around 0.15, which appears plausible value (I don't really know what band and what kind of land cover you have). So what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNAP uses scene metadata information to compute the reflectance value instead to add Digital Count value when a scene is loaded:

[Metadata reader:](https://github.com/senbox-org/s2tbx/blob/master/s2tbx-s2msi-reader/src/main/java/org/esa/s2tbx/dataio/s2/S2BandInformation.java#L77)

```
    public double getQuantificationValue() {
        return quantificationValue;
    }

    public double getScalingFactor() {
        return 1.0 / quantificationValue;
    }
```

[Band reader:](https://github.com/senbox-org/s2tbx/blob/master/s2tbx-s2msi-reader/src/main/java/org/esa/s2tbx/dataio/s2/Sentinel2ProductReader.java#L406)

```java
        S2BandInformation bandInformation = bandInfo.getBandInformation();
        band.setScalingFactor(bandInformation.getScalingFactor());

// Some lines after:

product.addBand(band);
```

The value of Quantification value is defined in .xml metadata file:

(line 58 of MTD_MSIL1C.xml)

`<QUANTIFICATION_VALUE unit="none">10000</L1C_TOA_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE>`

Also, SNAP uses a [default quantification value for L1C products](https://github.com/senbox-org/s2tbx/blob/master/s2tbx-s2msi-reader/src/main/java/org/esa/s2tbx/dataio/s2/l1c/L1cPSD13Constants.java#L54) (10000) if there is no QV in metadata.

Comment: Thank you! So since the reflectance values are already computed, I can continue processing the image without scaling it?

Comment: @dtanon yes, you can